# wordpress extremely slow on NAS

Tags: performance

i did a fresh wordpress install on my NAS and on my local machine (notebook).
on my notebook anything is running perfect (takes ~3 secs to load)
but from my NAS it is really extremely slow :( (taking ~12 secs)

it's the same setup and i couldn't find out the reason .. :(

it seems like that the problem is the internal siteurl (the nas' ip-address) and that wordpress is using it for all paths ..

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Where's the database sit? Local machine or NAS?

Comment: it's also at the nas.

Comment: Actually the thing is, when you store your code at server and run at your PC/laptop. it's slow because execution take place at your machine. and file request will be made from your NAS through LAN/WAN.

The best way is to create a Jail or run Instance of FreeBSD and install apache server on it. and run from NAS itself.

Then the wp website works like just another website from internet and much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you already answered the question yourself. The other thing could be that your NAS has a slow harddrive (5.400 rpm) or that your connection is slow.

---

Edit: Speed up with removing unwanted dashboard items...

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:    Dashboard-Widgets Removal Plugin
Plugin URI:     http://example.com
Description:    Disables admin UI dashboard widgets that you do not want
Author:         Franz Josef Kaiser
Author URI:     http://say-hello-code.com
Version:        0.1
License:        GPL v2 - http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/
/**
 * Disable unwanted Dashboard Admin UI Widgets
 */
function oxo_dashboard_widgets() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) 
        return;

    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    // Right Now - Comments, Posts, Pages at a glance
    # unset( $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_right_now'] );
    // Recent Comments
    # unset( $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_recent_comments'] );
    // Incoming Links
    # unset( $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_incoming_links'] );
    // Plugins - Popular, New and Recently updated Wordpress Plugins
    unset( $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_plugins'] );

    // Wordpress Development Blog Feed
    unset( $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_primary'] );
    // Other Wordpress News Feed
    unset( $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_secondary'] );
    // Quick Press Form
    # unset( $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_quick_press'] );
    // Recent Drafts List
    unset( $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_recent_drafts'] );
}
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'oxo_dashboard_widgets' );
?>
```

---

Edit #2:
Link to a debug plugin that offers time meassuring: [Blackbox Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blackbox-debug-bar/screenshots/)

Comment: i forgot to mention that filetransfer is really fast, also normal use of the webserver.
one thing i found out: disabling the dashboard's widgets did it speed up dramatically, but still ~2x slower than from the local machine.

Comment: Just adjust the plugin i added to your needs if it helps...

Comment: Oh, and look at the link at the bottom of the answer. Maybe this helps too figuring out where the delay is (ex. DB??).

Comment: thx for your reply - i already removed unwanted widgets + checked loading times with firebug.
it doesn't help really as with my local version even with widgets it loads fast, but not from the NAS - it all just takes much longer ..

Comment: The "Blackbox Bar" didn't help anything? It's imo better than firebug (afaik i only know how to look at the network tab) 'cause you can look far more into detail (queries, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I have design a test with SugarCRM in **[Performance Comparison on Retrieving Contacts from SugarCRM with QNAP TS-112, TS-212P, and TS-119PII](http://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2014/01/24/performance-comparison-on-retrieving-contacts-from-sugarcrm-with-qnap-ts-112-ts-212p-and-ts-119pii/)**. But since they are all AMP (Apache-MySQL-PHP) programs, maybe you are interested in the result.

[image]

I think the key to improve your performance are:

1. Disable unwanted service. eg. Media Library.
2. Get a powerful processor model. Atom-based models are better than Marvell 88F6282 SoC and Marvell 88F6281 SoC.

RAM upgrade doesn't bring enough improvement in my test.

To check if hard drive is the key component which slow down the process, I also do another test in **[QNAP TS-112 with OCZ SSD Performance Report](http://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/qnap-ts-112-with-ocz-ssd-performance-report/)**.

[image]

Unfortunately, even you replace the hard drive in NAS with SSD, the different are small. I don't think it will improve your WordPress dramatically as replace the processor.

Wish it helps!